# What does SWES mean in SNOWTAM?

Tags: snowtam

The resources explains that `SWEN` is the start for Snowtam. (Ref: [Snowtam help](https://www.ippc.no/ippc_doc/SNOWTAMhelp.pdf) ) But many snowtams I found starts with `SWES` which I could not find anything about. What is the difference? Can it have other values? Does snowtam always need to start with one of them?

Example Snowtam from [Pilotweb](https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/notamRetrievalByICAOAction.do?method=displayByICAOs&reportType=RAW&formatType=DOMESTIC&retrieveLocId=ESSB&actionType=notamRetrievalByICAOs)

```
SWES0701 ESSB 12270841 
(SNOWTAM 0701
A) ESSB
B) 12270841 C) 12 F) 4/4/4 G) 1/1/1 H) 5/5/5
N) G1 R S T Y Y1 Y2 Y3
Y4 Y5 YU YW/4/GOOD
R) 1 2 3 4 6 7 EAST NORTH/4/MEDIUM
T) RWY 12 BA 60/48/41. RWY 12 COVER 100 PERCENT. APRON SANDED. ICE
PATCHES ON APRON.)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snowtams follow the ICAO Format found in [ICAO Annex 15, Appendix 2](https://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/2361.pdf)[image]

This says that the abbreviated heading starts with SW** where ** is the ICAO location identifier. The location identifier document, [ICAO 7910 is a \$245 document](https://store.icao.int/products/location-indicators-doc-7910) so I can't link to it here, but all the Swedish airports start with location identifers that are "ES", hence any SNOWTAM you find from Sweden will be `SWES` reports. Reports for the United States typically start with "K" so they would be `SWK*`. Canada is "C", so `SWC*`.